# Filter Pandas Dataframe with or statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to to filter the dataframe using column 'closed_date', which contains dates. I am trying to filter so that either the value is null or the value is a date within the last year.

```py
df = df[(df['closed_date']>dt.today()-td(days=365)) | (df['closed_date'].isnull)]
```

This filter is what I am trying to get work but fails and gets this error

> Exception has occurred: AssertionError
> unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'bool' and 'method'

When I break it apart and try each aspect on its own, I get the expected results of dates within the last year or null.

Variants I have tried:

```py
df = df[(df['closed_date']>dt.today()-td(days=365)) or (df['closed_date'].isnull)]
```

Error:

> Exception has occurred: ValueError
> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```py
df = df[(df['closed_date']>dt.today()-td(days=365)) or (df['closed_date'].isnull())]
```

Error:

> Exception has occurred: ValueError
> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the parentheses to call the method `isnull`. Try:

```
df = df[(df['closed_date'] > dt.today() - td(days=365)) | (df['closed_date'].isnull())]
```

Answer (score 0):

isnull is [a function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-isnull/). As such, you need to call it as `df = df[(df['closed_date'] > dt.today() - td(days=365)) | (df['closed_date'].isnull())]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first method is missing the parentheses at the end of isnull

```
df = df[(df['closed_date']>dt.today()-td(days=365)) | (df['closed_date'].isnull())]
```